# C# - Method does not contain a definition for an object

Tags: c#

I have this block of code:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromBody] MonitorsDeleteRequest request)
{
    if (request == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Request could not be parsed.");
    }

    if (request.MonitorId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        return BadRequest("Query Monitor Id is required.");
    }

    try
    {
        await monitoringService.RemoveMonitorAsync(
            new RemoveMonitorRequest()
            {
                MonitorId = new MonitorId(request.MonitorId)
            });

        return Accepted();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError($"[{Request.Path.Value}]: {ex.ToString()}");
        return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The `MonitorId` that is inside the `RemoveMonitorRequest` method (on the left of the equal sign) is underlined in red - Intellisense says "`RemoveMonitorRequest does not contain a definition for MonitorId.`"

Just FYI, the other `MonitorId` earlier in the code has no Intellisense error.

What can I do to remedy this?

Comment: This suggests the `RemoveMonitorRequest` class does not have a `MonitorId` property. What does the `RemoveMonitorRequest` class look like?

Comment: @JonathonChase well wouldn't you know it - there is no RemoveMonitorRequest class!  I guess that explains it??  But why would this dev (who I considered to be extremely sharp and a great coder) make such a glaring omission?  Is there any circumstance at all where the non-existence of a RemoveMonitorRequest class makes sense?

Comment: And my post got down-voted, despite my best efforts.  @JonathonChase - I very much appreciate your helpful response even though I sometimes wonder whether I should even come here as a beginner.

Comment: Not your downvoter, but posting a question that begs not to be downvoted ... usually gets downvoted.  Just post the question and the relevant code and leave out that extra riff-raff.

Comment: @Stpete111 I would look at your monitorService's RemoveMonitorAsync method to see what type it's expecting. It could be the developer was working ahead  and simply hadn't gotten around to creating the types yet. If there's no `RemoveMonitorRequest` class, I would expect that to be your compilation error, not that it doesn't contain the definition. Perhaps it's in a referenced assembly, and not the project you are viewing.

Comment: @Jonathon Chase is right..Assuming that the  MonitorId is in the MonitorRequest class. Perhaps it would be worthwhile to verify it has public/internal " accessor next to it for example "public ..its datatype.. MonitorId"?

Comment: This is getting more confusing the more I try and dive in - performing Go to Definition for most of the classes/methods in this code take me somewhere that says "from metadata" so this thing could be dependent on a ton of other solutions for all I know.  I'm going to have to provide more context here for you all to really be able to help me.